# How can I escape special characters for a ModelAdmin fieldset name in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

In a Django ModelAdmin class, I declared some fieldsets to organize my fields. But whenever I use special characters in the name of the fieldset they are not rendered in the view. My admin.py has (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-) as the first line in order to use special characters.

So when I do this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import CentroEducativo

class CentroEducativoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Información General', {'fields':('codigo', 'codigo_sace', 'nombre', 'red_educativa','centro_educativo_tipo', 'admin_tipo','ingles')}),
        ('Ubicacion Geografica', {'fields':('ubicacion_x','ubicacion_y','direccion','distrito')})
    )

    search_fields = ['codigo_sace','codigo', 'nombre']  
    list_display = ('nombre','direccion','distrito')
    readonly_fields = ('codigo_sace','codigo',)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

admin.site.register(CentroEducativo, CentroEducativoAdmin)
```

The first fieldset name is not rendered, because it has an accent. While the second is displayed correctly.

Comment: This works fine for me - the fieldset is rendered with the correct label... could be an issue elsewhere, e.g., in your model?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6 @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: @solarissmoke each of the fields name is displayed correctly, so I don´t think is the model. The name of the section/fieldset is the one giving me trouble. In my example the phrase "Información General" is not being displayed because it has an accentuated "o" letter.

Comment: Yeah, the "o" displays correctly (with accent) for me using the code you have provided. I wonder if it is a platform issue. Also possibly check that your text editor is saving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: @solarissmoke It was being saved as ANSI, changing it to UTF-8 did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **solarissmoke** suggested in the comments, files should be saved as UTF-8. My file was being saved as ANSI and that was generating the bug.

I used notepad++ to convert it to UTF-8 without BOM.